# how to interpret pygit2 status info

Tags: python, git, pygit2

I am using pygit2 to access that status of the repo

```
status = repo.status()

for filepath,flags in status.items():
    print ("path %s flags %d", filepath, flags)
```

I dont seem to be able to find any documentation on how to interpret the flags

Could someone point me in the rigth direction please

Comment: Can you show sample output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.pygit2.org/working-copy.html#status) seems to be pretty clear on this:

> Repository.status() → {str: int}
>
> Reads the status of the repository and returns a dictionary with file paths as keys and status flags as values. See pygit2.GIT_STATUS_*.

And here you have em: https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2/blob/320ee5e733039d4a3cc952b287498dbc5737c353/src/pygit2.c#L312-L320

Comment: Thanks for the link - I saw pygit2.GIT_STATUS_* but could not find the link

Comment: IMHO documentation which forces you to read source code does not count as "pretty clear".

Comment: @AdamSpiers especially when the source code does not say anything either. It just lists the flags. ***What is the meaning of each flag?***

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to extract the pygit2 status codes. Here's an example.

Output of `git status` for some unstaged commits:

```
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
    deleted:    deleted.txt
    modified:   modified.txt
Untracked files:
    added.txt
```

pygit2 status output

```
repo.status()
#{'added.txt': 128, 'deleted.txt': 512, 'modified.txt': 256}
```

Status codes from pygit2

```
from pygit2 import GIT_STATUS_WT_NEW, GIT_STATUS_WT_DELETED, GIT_STATUS_WT_MODIFIED
print("GIT_STATUS_WT_NEW", GIT_STATUS_WT_NEW)
print("GIT_STATUS_WT_DELETED", GIT_STATUS_WT_DELETED)
print("GIT_STATUS_WT_MODIFIED", GIT_STATUS_WT_MODIFIED)
#GIT_STATUS_WT_NEW 128
#GIT_STATUS_WT_DELETED 512
#GIT_STATUS_WT_MODIFIED 256
```

For staged commits, the relevant status codes are `GIT_STATUS_INDEX_NEW`, `GIT_STATUS_INDEX_DELETED`, `GIT_STATUS_INDEX_MODIFIED`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This will print all status codes

```
import pygit2

for entry in dir(pygit2):
    if entry.startswith('GIT_'):
        enum_val = getattr(pygit2, entry)
        print(entry + ': ' + str(enum_val))
```